# Disable/Trim DHTML Menu Description Popup

Tags: taxonomy-terms, routes, navigation

I would like to disable or trim DHTML Menu's description popup. I have checked both dhtml_menu and taxonomy modules. I could not get any clues. Please help me.

Thanks